# Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET MVC1.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2010 to write code for shared hosting that is designed for .NET 3.5 and ASP.NET MVC 1.0? I've been trying for a while to get a project to run that uses only 1.0 features, and it just will not translate over very well.

Comment: ASP.Net 1.0 is very different from ASP.Net MVC 1.0 - you might want to edit your title  ;)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Just an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure and change the Target Framework in the project properties to 3.5 if your using the MVC 1. This should prevent some of the "translation issues" I think your describing.

Maybe you should clarify what "just will not translate over very well" means.

Comment: Well, it doesn't run. It just says that the MVC .dll files won't work when I publish it to the web server.

Comment: Thats even vaguer...    What says it wont' work, the exception message?  Maybe you should post the actual error message?

Comment: Sure. I will try to do that. I'll return shortly with more information, not at my machine at this very instant.

Comment: Apparently I had an installation error from the getgo, and it had nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In addition you may try to re-include the reference to System.Web.Mvc. When I went from vs08 to vs10, and opened an old project, it still upgraded the reference to 2.0.0.0.

Luckily, I had a untouched version of the old project, which contained the old dll-file. So I deleted the new reference, and included the older version (1.0.0.0). Now it works fine^_^