# I cannot Model.Count in view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am responsible to maintain legacy system. The system was developed from Visual Studio 2008 and MVC 1.0. However, the version of visual studio I have is 2010. Now I am faced with new problem that Model object in View cannot use the method from original class. The following is header of view file.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of System.Linq.IQueryable(Of MVCApplication.opportunity))"%>
```

In the view part, I have following code.

```
    <%  If (Model.Count <> 0) Then%>
```

However, when I try to use member 'Count', there is System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'Count' on type 'DataQuery(Of opportunity)' not found.

In debug mode, model contain the same data as the controller. However, it seems the view page cannot access them. Do you have any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to upgrade the legacy system?

You can still download MVC 1 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

[Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET MVC1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917190/visual-studio-2010-with-asp-net-mvc1-0)

Comment: I have this problem after using MVC 1.0 with Visual Studio 2010. After I changed back to MVC 2.0, this problem is gone. However, I got another problem on compatiability. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to upgrade a project from VS2008+MVC1 to VS2010+MVC4BETA and I also started facing the similar kind of issues. It gives an error on Model.xxxx. The problem what we find is that the code does not typecast the relevant Model to its actual object type rather it remains as Object only.

I have the following header of view file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Employee>" %>
```

Then using the following line to access one of the property of Employee object

```
    <%=ViewData.Model.Name %>
```

What I am doing to get this working, we are doing type casting explicitly for the object coming in ViewData.Model as follows:

```
    <% Employee model = (Employee)ViewData.Model;%>
```

Then using the below code works well

```
    <%=model.Name %>
```

Hope this helps some one. However I am not sure why this was required.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that the [IQueryable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) does not have a `Count` property. 
Have you tried this?

```
<% If (Model.Count() <> 0) Then %>
```

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. It seems Model cannot recognize every property of IQueryable inteface. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: No such thing , in Razor attempting to do such blows up  @if(Model.Count() <> 0)
                   {  .... }

Comment: If something is not working, I'm pretty sure the problem isn't with the Count() method. I'm using it in my current project and everything is fine. Make sure that the type of the Model is IEnumerable.